# Linq get Date from DateTime nullable field

Tags: linq

I have the following where I need to get only the Date (not datetime) from
ReqDate and RepDeclined which are both nullable datetime fields.

```
    var info = from pr in db.Prog
       join tf in db.In_Lens
       on pr.PID equals tf.PID
       select new
       { ReqDate = String.Format("{0:MM/dd/yyyy}",tf.ReqDate),
         ReqDeclinedDate = tf.ReqDeclined.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy")
       }).ToList()
```

It is not working as ReqDate and RepDeclined are both nullable datetime fields.
I also tried String.Format but no luck.

It says no overload for method.

Comment: Generally, you would need `nullableDate.Value.ToString(format)`, but I'm not sure that would work with EF (or whatever provider you are using). In normal code, you would need to be sure `nullableDate` isn't null, otherwise you might use `nullableDate.GetValueOrDefault()` instead of Value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this, more elegant i think

```
  var info = from pr in db.Prog
       join tf in db.In_Lens
       on pr.PID equals tf.PID
       select new
       { ReqDate = !string.IsNullOrEmpty(tf.ReqDate) ? string.Format("{0:MM/dd/yyyy}",tf.ReqDate) : string.Empty(),
         ReqDeclinedDate = !string.IsNullOrEmpty(tf.ReqDeclined) ? tf.ReqDeclined.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy") : string.Empty()
       }).ToList()
```

Answer (score 0):

I just way changed my answer.. basically.. you need to get back a couple datetimes in your new collection.. and then when you use those values, you can do the String.Format(). The reason is LINQ boils down to SQL, and there's no String.Format() converter (yet?).

so when you loop through the results, you can transform those results to display propertly (i.e. String.Format(...)).. but you will not be able to select out and convert the results in one linq statement, you might be able to do it LAMBDA (.ForEach()), which would be able to iterate through the results, however, it would just be a shorhtand way of doing what i described above..

...to the best of my knowledge

Comment: Thanks. I am getting the following: LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.String Format(System.String, System.Object)' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression."}

Comment: oh, that's right.. i dont think you can do much formatting in a query because it's going to try to turn it into SQL